# How can I use Selectize.js with Angular2?

Tags: angular, selectize.js

I'm trying to implement Selectize.js with Angular2 but I can't seem to make it work. Here's what I've tried in the HTML component:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="friends">Friends</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" #friends
            [(ngModel)]="user.friends" name="friends"
            #picture="ngModel">
  </div>
```

And the in the component:

```
declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  providers: [ AuthenticationService, UserService, MessageService ]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('friends') el:ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _authService: AuthenticationService,
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    $('#friends').selectize({
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      create: function(input) {
        return {
          value: input,
          text: input
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    //...
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    //...
  }

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is simply implement Selectize in the friends input. I want the user to be able to write the names of his friends and then recuperate them in Angular with an array of names.

But nothing happens in the interface, Selectize doesn't do anything. How come?

Answer (score 3):

To hopefully make this a bit easier I've created the ng2-selectize component available on github & npm.

Its usage could be:

```js
export class MultiSelectExampleComponent {
  options = [{
  label: 'Angular 2',
  value: 'angular2'
 }, {
  label: 'ReactJS',
  value: 'reactjs'
 }
  ];
  config = {
    labelField: 'label',
    valueField: 'value',
    highlight: false,
    create:false,
    persist:true,
    plugins: ['dropdown_direction', 'remove_button'],
    dropdownDirection: 'down',
    maxItems: 5
  };
  placeholder: string = 'Placeholder...';
  value:string[];

  onValueChange($event) {
    console.log("Option changed: ", $event);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <ng2-selectize [config]="config" [options]="options" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"></ng2-selectize>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding to selectize doesn't work in angular2, so get rid of those ngModels. Instead, this is what I do is implement the onItemAdd and onItemRemove functions in selectize, like so:

```
activateSelectize() {
    var $selecitize= jQuery('.selectize');

    this.select= $selectize.selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        create: (input) => {
            return {
                value: input,
                text: input
            };
        },
        onItemAdd: (value) => {
            this.updateValue({selected: value});
        },
        onItemRemove: (value) => {
            this.updateValue({deselected: value});
        },
    });
 }
```

And this is the html:

```
<select class="selectize">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option[0]}}">{{option[1]}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get selectize.js to work with (Angular 8 tested) without the ng2-selectize plugins (extra weight) you can do the following:

Install the plugin via NPM:

```
npm i selectize
```

Then install the types so you can get access to intellisense and also remove any undeclared methods that typescript doesn't understand that's associated with selectize.

```
npm i @types/selectize
```

Now in your component you need to import the plugin, do so with the following: (make sure your path to node_modules is correct in your app from your component)

```
import 'node_modules/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js';
```

You'll need jQuery if you haven't imported/installed this already. Now in your component use the AfterViewInit() method - if loading upon first initialisation of the page so you know the DOM has been created. Like so:

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      $(<selector>).selectize({<options-object>});
}
```

Then similar to what Rob is suggesting, utilise one of the following methods that selectize offers: [documentation here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

```
onChange: (value) => {}, onItemAdd: (value, $item) => {}
```

This should get you up and running with the plugin, you'll need to import the CSS themes or use your own styling.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-selectize

And it works perfectly in my angular 5 project